# Unique items from Access to Excel

Tags: sql, excel, combobox

I have this code:

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strSql As String
Dim strConnection As String
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=\\lm\central\Permkt\Svc02-User-Disk\Sales\Sales-Private\Consumer Marketing\Marketing Analytics\Testing Framework\2014Data.accdb"
strSql = "SELECT distinct project1 FROM 2014Data"
cn.Open strConnection
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)

rw = 1

    For Each myfield In rs.Fields
    Cells(rw, 7) = myfield
    rw = rw + 1
    Next myfield




rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

End Sub

And now i am getting the first project1 in the cell as a value, but I should have two unique project1's . How would I get to the second? 
Thanks so much for the first comments, the SQL is at least now executing but not sending back both project1 items

Comment: are you sure your table name is 2014Data ? (i'm noticing this is your DB name...)

Comment: You can't just feed a string to rowsource, you have to execute the query using the string.  I don't have the time this second to give you the syntax, but it's the basic recordset syntax for running an sql query.

Answer (score 0):

You have **Dim**'ed *rs*,but never **Set** *rs*

Comment: Actually, she never uses rs, which is the problem.  The query is never executed.

Comment: @LanceRoberts .............you are correct.......it is never used.........it must be **Set** before it is used or **Close** 'd.

Comment: It's the Set statement that would actually call the query.

Answer (score 0):

I did some stuff on running SQL within VBA:

```
Public Sub GetCn(ByRef dbcon As ADODB.Connection, ByRef dbrs As ADODB.Recordset, _
sqlstr As String, servername As String, dbname As String)

Set dbcon = New ADODB.Connection
dbcon.CursorLocation = adUseClient
dbcon.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI;Server=" & servername & ";Database=" & dbname & ";Trusted_Connection=yes;"
'"PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & dbfile & ";", _
'usernm , pword

Set dbrs = New ADODB.Recordset
'Debug.Print sqlstr
dbcon.CommandTimeout = 200
Debug.Print sqlstr
dbrs.Open sqlstr, dbcon

End Sub

Public Sub RunSQL(sql As String)

Dim adoconn As ADODB.Connection
Dim adors As ADODB.Recordset
Dim dbname As String
Dim servername As String

servername = Worksheets("DBSettings").Range("B1").value
dbname = Worksheets("DBSettings").Range("B2").value

Call GetCn(adoconn, adors, sql, servername, dbname)
End Sub
Sub OpenDatabaseConnection(ByVal servername As String, ByVal databasename As String, sql As String, myRange As Range)
    Dim connectionstring As String
    'Dim SQL As String
    Dim adoconn As ADODB.Connection
Dim adors As ADODB.Recordset




Dim dbname As String
If servername = "" Then servername = Worksheets("DBSettings").Range("B1").value
If databasename = "" Then databasename = Worksheets("DBSettings").Range("B2").value

Call GetCn(adoconn, adors, sql, servername, databasename)

NrOfRows = adors.RecordCount
myRange.CopyFromRecordset adors

'LOOP DOOR KOLOMMEN en OUTPUT Columns 1 rij hoger
Dim fieldname As String, counter As Integer
counter = 1
Dim StartRange As Range
Set StartRange = myRange.Worksheet.Range("A1")
For Each Field In adors.Fields
    StartRange.Cells(1, counter).value = Field.name
    counter = counter + 1
Next

adors.Close
adoconn.Close
Set adors = Nothing
Set adoconn = Nothing

Dim sn() As Variant, wsnn As String
wsnn = myRange.Worksheet.name
sn = Array(wsnn)
'Call NameDeletionV3(sn)
'Call CreateName("RawData", CreateRange(Worksheets(sn), CInt(1), GetLastColumn(Worksheets(sn)), CInt(1), GetLastRow(Worksheets(sn))), Worksheets(sn))
'myRange = Worksheets("Q1-old").Range("B1")



End Sub
```

and then for usage:

```
Sub SQL_Execute()

Dim sql As String, FromDate As Date, EndDate As Date


sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME"

Dim myRange As Range
Dim sheetname As String: sheetname = "Sheet1"

Worksheets(sheetname).Cells.Delete


Set myRange = Worksheets(sheetname).Range("A2")
Debug.Print sql
Call OpenDatabaseConnection("", "", sql, myRange)




End Sub
```